# Application Memory Leak based on metrics

Tags: php, bash, amazon-ec2, zend-framework2, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have a zf2 php application which is executed in a bash script every minute. This is running inside an ec2 instance.

here's my code

```
while :
do
   php public/index.php start-processor &
   wait
   sleep 60
done
```

Metrics Reading

[image]

[image]

Based on the metrics it keeps on leaking memory until it reaches 100% then drops. Is this normal or is there really a leak happening to my application?

I've also tried using htops and it looks fine and does not eat memory that much.
[image]

Hope someone could explain what is happening here. Should I worry about this?
Thanks and more power.

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like a memory leak to me, there the used amount would just rise and never go back, causing you app to eventually crash.

This graph looks very similar to garbage collection as it's happening in JVM, does you PHP use such thing under the hood? I searched the web and looks like PHP 5.3+ has GC built in: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php

Comment: Hmm. Yes PHP does have this garbage collection. Just don't know how it works. If this is how garbage collection works why does it have to wait for the memory usage to become 100% before running garbage collection. Is it possible that i can set max memory usage then run garbage collection? Thanks and more power.

Comment: Read up on GC basics and principles, I'm sure you will find plenty online. It might not be bad to run GC only after the memory is almost all taken, it might be the fastest approach compared to e.g. running the GC more frequently when memory use is only 50%. It is not bad to use all the memory you have, the free one would only be wasted resources :-)